# Why is this code giving me an error about a weak property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

This is my simple piece of code on iOS, using ARC:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
    NSObject *objStrong;
    NSObject *objWeek;
}
@property(strong) NSObject *objStrong;
//getting error at this line
@property(weak) NSObject *objWeek; //Existing ivar 'objWeek' for _week property 'objWeek' must be _week 

@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize objStrong;
@synthesize objWeek;

@end
```

When I try to compile, the compiler complains about an existing ivar 'objWeek' for _weak property 'objWeek'. Why isn't this code compiling correctly?

Comment: "NSObject *objStrong;" is declared in the interface and "@property(strong) NSObject *obj;" is declared underneath.  Why did you change the names?

Comment: @Javy thanks oh typo mistake...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's complaining because the backing variable, `NSObject *objWeek` is declared as `__strong` (all otherwise unannotated Objective C pointers to retainable objects are `__strong`). Change the backing variable to be `__weak NSObject *objWeek`, and the compiler will like you again.

Edit: As requested, the ARC documentation from LLVM's clang:

> 4.4.1. Objects
>
> If an object is declared with retainable object owner type, but
>   without an explicit ownership qualifier, its type is implicitly
>   adjusted to have __strong qualification.
>
> As a special case, if the object's base type is Class (possibly
>   protocol-qualified), the type is adjusted to have __unsafe_unretained
>   qualification instead.

Link: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.inference

Comment: could you please give me the link of above reference(all otherwise unannotated Objective C pointers are strong) in apples references..

Answer (score 1):

Same problem I have faced. I did spend lot of time on this finally I could solve this problem by cleaning the project.Here is the way....

product->clean

The reason is you may be deleted controller class(ViewController) but still it is not removed from your project.when you finish cleaning of your project the error will be gone automatically. This worked for me...

Comment: I already got the solution and I have accepted it too. Moreover the very first thing that an iOS developer or xcode user does is Cleaning the project when s/he faces some weird unknown errors.